# Benefits of native ActionBar vs custom implementation?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I would like to try and use the native Google ActionBar class for my application however, I would like to be able to change the left most image dynamically, disable the icon and center the title. I was wondering if this is possible of if I should implement my own ActionBar?

My reason for wanting to change the left most image (IE the navigation drawer indicator) is because I am using the navigation drawer but on some screens would like to display the up indicator instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the documentation for the ActionBarDrawerToggle, there is a method to enable/disable the navigation drawer icon (setDrawerIndicatorEnabled), when disabled it reverts to the home-as-up indicator.

Another option is to recreate the drawer in those specific screens you want the icon different and specify the new icon in the creation of the drawer, not sure if this would work though.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home) is the android guide which explains how to do this, but allow me to give a brief overview.

You do not have to have the app icon as the leftmost icon so in certain pages you can disable it by specifying another "android:logo" item in the XML file, or by simply diabling it entirely.

The android logo, which is what you are talking about as the "leftmost item", can have an onClickListener() set for it which is how you can change it simply to an uparrow image which you can download from [google](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Sorry but by left most icon i ment the three stacked bars [here](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-EbvwHgYfoQ8/UZeTVdEGn2I/AAAAAAAAQok/AoJ1_NqjyGg/s400/framed_2013-05-18_12.32.09_copy.png) Once the navigation drawer icon is displayed I would like to be able to manually switch to the up icon. The only way I have found to do this is to getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) however, this leads to an inconsistant navigation bar.